# The value of $\lim_{ n\to \infty} (n^2)/((n^2+1)(n^2+4)(n^2+9)\ldots(n^2+n^2))^{1/n}$ is

Tags: calculus

First, take $n^2$ common from the denominator and out of the $n$-th root. $n^2$ in numerator gets cancelled with the one taken common in the denominator

Next, we assume the value of limit to be $L$ and take $\log$ $(\ln)$ on both sides. We get to see a standard form of integration of the limit of sum.

Now, on solving it we get the final answer in terms of $e$.

My doubt is when we take $n^2$ common as mentioned in the first sentence, we get a term of $1/n^2$ in every single bracket in the denominator. As $n\to\infty$, $1/n^2 \to 0.$ If we solve using this method, we get the value of limit as $1.$

Which method is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

$$
L:={n^2\over\Pi_{r=1}^n(n^2+r^2)^{1\over n}}={1\over\Pi_{r=1}^n(1+{r^2\over n^2})^{1\over n}}\\ \ \\ \ \\
\log L=-{1\over n}\sum_{r=1}^n \log\left(1+{r^2\over n^2}\right)
$$

This is a reimann summation

$$
\log L=-\int_0^1\log(1+x^2)dx=2-\log 2-{\pi\over 2}
$$

So $$L={e^{2-{\pi\over2}}\over 2}$$

Note: The reason you can't take limit value as 1 is because you have $1\over n$ as exponent and $\lim(1+{r^2\over n^2})^{1\over n}\neq1$

Think about $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+{1\over x})^x=e$$

Note:

This was a reply to the comment but it was too big too fit

I asked you think about that example to see how exponents effect limits

$$\Pi(1+{r^2\over n^2})^{1\over n}=(1+{n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6n^2}\cdots)^{1\over n}$$

It is immediate that this is of model $\infty^0$ which is an indeterminate form similar to $0\over 0$ so we can't directly compute it

Comment: But, this is in the form of 1 raised to infinity. I did not understand the reason you have asked me to think on this. Can you please clarify a bit more.